# jQuery regex match function always returns false

Tags: jquery, regex, forms, validation, match

I try to make a simpel form valitation function in jQuery, but in some way this function always returns that de input is false. Can you help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>input.notoke { border: 1px solid red; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#validate :input").each(function(){
    $(this).on("change paste keyup", function() {  

      if ( $(this).val().match( $(this).attr('data-regex') ) ){
        $(this).removeClass('notoke');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('notoke');
      }

    });
  });
}); 
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h3>Formulier</h3>
      <form role="form" id="validate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" data-regex="^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" data-regex="/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$/">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't see were I'm wrong... can you help me out?

I tried with 'alert' to see the values of $(this).val and $(this).attr('data-regex') but this seems all fine to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Anything read from DOM is string**

You've to use the `RegExp` constructor and pass the **string** to it to convert the string to Regular Expression.

```
if ($(this).val().match(new RegExp($(this).attr('data-regex')))) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, note that there is no need of delimiter slashes in the string.

And make sure to double escape the some metacharacters if needed

For example, to match digits use

```
\\d
```

I'll also suggest to use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check if the string satisfies the regex instead of [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
if (new RegExp($(this).data('regex')).test($(this).val())) {
```

---

Also, the jQuery code can be shortened.

```
$("form#validate :input").on("change paste keyup", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('notoke', !new RegExp($(this).data('regex')).test($(this).val()));
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/e2k84d7n/)

Comment: Thank your for your quick respone. Unfortunatly, your suggestion leaves me with an error: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).test is not a function**

Comment: @FJ-web sorry, typo there. Wrong parenthesis. Use `new RegExp($(this).data('regex')).test($(this).val())`.

Comment: Thnx. But still only false as a result. Is there something wrong with my data-regex attribute?

Comment: @FJ-web Works for me. [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ybdrpow7/) Note that in RegEx, yo're only using `A-Z`, so lowercase letters will not be included. you've to include them by adding `a-z` in the character class.